# Can a changelist only contain one file which is part of a larger branch?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

This is what I have done:

1. Branch from trunk (v 1.0.0)
2. Create new branch (v 1.0.1)
   2.1 - with the creation of a branch about 50 files were requested
3. Finalized changes, the change only needed to happen on 1 file
4. --- here is where I want to optimize my work

On my first pass I merged all files and I asked Perforce to keep my newest copy of all the files even tho they didn't change. So my question is.

When I merge back, if I tell Perforce to keep the originals that didn't change does that mean that my change list will only contain one file which is the one that changed? Or when I create my branch the first time I have to only branch the one file that I will be updating. Of course that would be hard to know ahead of time.

Comment: What part of this process do you feel needs "optimized".  Sounds like you did it right.

Comment: Hi @raven, I was making the mistake of forcing a merge even tho all the files didn't change which was giving me the desire product but not the procedure I was expecting. I was able to figure out that I only needed to merge those files that had changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the process was correct and the optimization was not necessary. However it is important to note that when you are merging you can opt-out contents that haven't changed.